# Get latest two documents in Mongo aggregagte query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am using aggregate query to fetch multiple data from various Collections. Some of the collections have more than one records, I there a way where I can get latest(by latest i mean recently added) two records from particular collection.

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: whats ur definition for `latest`? and where is ur data set?

Comment: Look into $facet where the individual stages inside the $facet would have a $lookup, a $sort and a $limit.